# Does relativism start with Hegel?

Tags: hegel, relativism

I don't think I need to ellaborate but Hegel's themes of historicism, revelation, and, of course, the dialectic, along with affirming the Weltgeist and denying Kant's thing in itself seem to be very abstract but effective origins for what relativism became. Am I right in assuming this or did relativism start before or after Hegel?

Comment: Hegel is most famous for his universal unity of dialectic treatment and his absolute will (zeitgeist) from which hardly I see any link to relativism... A google search of relativism here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativism)  says: " Sophists are considered the founding fathers of relativism in Western philosophy. Elements of relativism emerged among the Sophists in the 5th century BC. Notably, it was Protagoras..."

Comment: Not only did it not start with Hegel, Hegel was not even a relativist, he was an [absolute idealist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_idealism). Kant and Hegel are no more responsible for the uses later generations made of them than Plato and Aristotle.

Comment: Relevant: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/57162/17209

Comment: I encountered a reading of the Continental-Analytic split, as traditions joined at Kant, and divided by Hegel. I wonder if that kind of thing motivated your agenda-heavy post. Like postmodernism & nihilism, relativism historically started as a pejorative, a negative identification, only later taken up as a positive identification, & similarly not really a concisely coherent stance.